# db:migrate: table is not being created but other tables are?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubymine

I just tried to add 2 new tables into my schema, events and calendars. When running the `db:migrate`, it ran without errors, but only the `events` table has been picked up and put into the visual database. Why is this happening? Is it something to do with the has_many / belongs_to association? Very frustrating!

I have just run the `db:migrate:status` and it has shown:

```
Status Migration ID   Migration Name
up     20151002160900 Create messages
up     20151123214812 Create calendars
up     20151123220903 Create customers
up     20151123221638 Create businesses
up     20151213150347 Create events
```

So it is creating calendars allegedly, but it's not appearing in my database to the side. Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is my database schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151213150347) do
  create_table "businesses", force: true do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "normal_password_digest"
    t.string "manager_password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "customers", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer "business_id"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "remember_digest"
    t.string "role"
  end

  create_table "events", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer "calendar_id"
    t.text "name"
    t.datetime "start"
    t.datetime "end"
    t.string "location"
  end

  create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

these are my 2 migration files:

```
class CreateCalendars < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def change 
    create_table :calendars do |t|
      t.timestamps
      t.references :customer, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name
      t.string :googlePass
      t.string :googleID
    end
  end
end 

class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def change 
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.timestamps
      t.references :calendar, foreign_key: true
      t.text :name
      t.datetime :start
      t.datetime :end
      t.string :location
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried running `db:migrate` on just create_calendars and it just removed everything and did not create the table.

I have tried running `db:drop` and `db:setup`.

I have looked at my events table text and although it contains 'calendar_id', this is not a foreign key, as there is no calendar table (im assuming).

Why is this happening?

Comment: I would assume that the column named `:end` causes the issue. Can you try changing to a non-reserved Ruby keyword and retry from the beginning?

Comment: that is not the table that wont be created though

Comment: How do you check if table is created?
What happens after running `db:drop` and `db:migrate`?
Also try running `rake db:migrate:down VERSION= 20151123214812` and `rake db:migrate:up VERSION= 20151123214812`. And pay attention to the output in console, it should print something.

Comment: A good practice which helps you avoid using Ruby keywords like `end` and `begin` is to postfix date and time columns with `_at` ie `starts_at` and `ends_at`. You'll notice that ActiveRecord does this for the default timestamps. And it reads like english: `event.starts_at`

Comment: when I run db:drop followed by db:migrate, should I be migrating with version being 'latest migration'? I am using RubyMine IDE.

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to have worked! Thank you everyone, I have also changed my :start and :end to starts_at and ends_at

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing that problem if the migration run in the past but has been changed afterwards. Rails is storing the status of a migration by the timestamp only. It does not track changes in migration files.

You can easily find out be re-running the calendars migration

```
$ bin/rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20151123214812
$ bin/rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20151123214812
```

Find out more about [resetting migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#resetting-the-database) and [reverting migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#reverting-previous-migrations).

Comment: so how would I go about fixing it?